# iReport send generated PDF report via email

Tags: php, laravel, email, jasper-reports

I'm using jasper report iReport 5.6.0 to create dynamic reports for a company.
I integrated the reporting tool with my php web application, it's working. I created export options in the html template and a preview button in an **IFRAME**

I don't want to put the iframe in a php variable and send it to the email function. I can generate the report as downloadable pdf, xls .. file, can i send this file automatically as an attachment to an email ?

I'm using laravel framework, the code for generating and exporting the report:

```
    use JasperPHP\JasperPHP;

public function xmlToPdf()
    {
        $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_CancelAck';
        $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_CancelAck';
        $ext = "pdf";
        $data_file = public_path() . '/report/CancelAck.xml';
        $driver = 'xml';
        $xml_xpath = '/CancelResponse/CancelResult/ID';

        \JasperPHP::process(
            public_path() . '/report/CancelAck.jrxml', 
            $output, 
            array($ext),
            array(),
            array('data_file' => $data_file, 'driver' => $driver, 'xml_xpath' =>   $xml_xpath),                   
            false,
            false
        )->execute();

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.time().'_CancelAck.'.$ext);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output.'.'.$ext));
        flush();
        readfile($output.'.'.$ext);
        unlink($output.'.'.$ext);

    }
```

is there any solution to export this report as attachment for email (php) ?

Comment: Do you want to get the data out of the iFrame and put it into your php application which creates the html page?

Comment: yes 100% sorry for late reply, timezone

Comment: Please see [this page](http://www.zomeoff.com/javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe/) regarding a similar idea where the iframe is filled from the page. As far as I understand it, it would be more of a hack to load from an iframe if it is possible at all (different domains, browsers might prevent this).

Comment: i got my response and its appearing in the iframe, now this content i want to send it in an email body using php

Comment: Yes, understood. Did you check the link and see my information?